# Multi column and Shrink-Wrap

Tags: html, css

I ve been trying to make a layout that has a fixed height and creates as many
columns of a certain size as need be to show some flow text. This works, but when I put it inside a div the div doesn't adopt the size of the contents (meaning: the red color in the example goes over the entire width of the page if the page can contain the whole text and if I get a horizontal scroll-bar it doesn't go over the initial field of vision). I tried several methods for shrink-wrapping from this page http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap. However none of them worked.

Here the example code:

```
<body style="">
    <div style="background: red; display: inline-block; -webkit-column-width: 300px; -moz-column-width: 300px; height: 100px;">
        <p style="float: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Suspendisse blandit commodo dolor, et dapibus sem ultrices in.
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            In ac elit aliquet felis vestibulum iaculis. Donec nec risus at justo luctus vestibulum.
            Proin mollis sapien et odio interdum tempus.
            Mauris consequat arcu vitae justo tempor quis mattis magna pulvinar.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried this with chromium and firefox. Also, the shrink-wrap works if I leave out the height and colunm-with and instead put just a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

`column-width` is not the issue. Setting the `height` to `auto` alone should do the trick.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XTGTY/

Comment: Yes, but i want a fixed height (preferably the height of the browser window but I think I figured that out), so lets say for simplicity's sake a fixed height of 100px.

Comment: You can have a fixed height. But then that height should be set to the `<p>` and not the `<div>` containing it.

Comment: In firefox height in <p> doesn't seem to have any effect at all and in chromium it doesn't have the desired effect and eats up some of the sentences at the end.

Comment: I think height in <p> sets the height of all columns if stacked on top of each other. But I want to set the height of the red box